# How to create custom user defined data type in Hive

Tags: hive, teradata, user-defined-types

Is there any way to create custom user defined data type in Hive? I want to move some table data from Teradata database to Hive. But in Teradata database tables, there are few columns data type that are not supported in Hive. So to map the source table columns to my destination table columns in Hive, I want to create my own data type in Hive.

I know about writing UDF's in Hive but have no idea about creating user defined data type in Hive. Any idea and example on the same would be of great help.

Comment: What are the types in your columns that are not supported?

Comment: Interval, BLOB, CLOB, varbyte are some of the data type in teradata database that are not present in hive